# CSS : Amazingly strikethrough not working on child display:inline-block div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code where if I apply **text-decoration: line-through;** on outer div, all the inner div elements also must be ***'strikethroughed'***. This works 100% fine normally; But, if I put the child elements as '**display:inline-block**', now the strikethrough applied to the parent div does not effect the strikeness to the childs. I have to put the childs as display:inline-block and I need the childs to be crossed out at the addition of **text-decoration: line-through;** to the ***parent div***.

```css
div{padding:10px;}
#outer{background:yellow;text-decoration: line-through;}
#inner{background:pink;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div id=outer> 
  <div id=inner>
    This is the text 
  </div> 
</div>
```

This is an office project, and your help is appreciated !

Comment: you missed `"` quotes around `id`. like `id="outer"`

Comment: It wont effect bro. That's not the problem. Results would be same ...

Comment: @AmitSoni Not required in HTML5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `text-decoration:inherit`.

```css
div{padding:10px;}
#outer{background:yellow;text-decoration: line-through;}
#inner{background:pink;display:inline-block; text-decoration:inherit}
```

```html
<div id=outer> 
  <div id=inner>
    This is the text 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Normally, `text-decoration` is not an inherited property, so the inner div has an implicit `text-decoration:none`, the default. By using `inherit`, you tell the element that it should have the same text decoration as its parent.

Comment: `inherit` instructs the element to adopt the css style from its parent

Comment: I edited the question to explain why it works. However, a far better question would be how come the line is visible through the inner div if it's `block` or `inline`. I'm not sure I can answer that.

Comment: I'm surprised that `text-decoration` isn't inherited; I thought all styles were inherited by default. Especially because of this "[Text decorations draw across descendant elements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)"

Comment: `Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables`. The explanation is right there : [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-decoration). Which mean unless it's duly specified, the children element won't inherit the property.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Many styles are inherited, but by no means all. [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#properties) is a list.

Answer (score 6):

The default value for `text-decoration` is `none`, so you need to specify a value if you want it to be different. Use `inherit` to use the parent's value:

```
#outer > div { text-decoration: inherit; }
```

or adapt the css for `#inner` to include `text-decoration: inherit;`:

```
#inner { background: pink; display: inline-block; text-decoration: inherit; }
```

---

**Example**

```css
div{padding:10px;}
#outer{background:yellow;text-decoration: line-through;}
#inner{background:pink;display:inline-block; text-decoration: inherit; }
```

```html
<div id=outer> 
  <div id=inner>
    This is the text 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why does `inherit` make a difference here? Shouldn't that be the default?

Comment: `text-decoration` has the value `none` automatically so you need to specify a value if you want it to be different